# Lost connection to device when debugging

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code as my IDE for Flutter development. I'm running the app on an Android emulator Pixel 2 API 28.

Problem:
Whenever I try to run the `Flutter run` command in cmd I get a message `Lost connection to device`.

```
I/OpenGLRenderer( 8484): Davey! duration=1122ms; Flags=1, 
IntendedVsync=6065658887920, Vsync=6066275554562, 
OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, 
HandleInputStart=6066285882120, AnimationStart=6066285961770, 
PerformTraversalsStart=6066287810650, DrawStart=6066297042570, 
SyncQueued=6066299589490, SyncStart=6066304787990, 
IssueDrawCommandsStart=6066305258460, SwapBuffers=6066689863430, 
FrameCompleted=6066786911240, DequeueBufferDuration=43132000, 
QueueBufferDuration=733000,
D/EGL_emulation( 8484): eglMakeCurrent: 0xcbb143c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 
0xe47d8860)
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

The error I get when I try to run my application. This is the first time that this error has happened to me. I don't think I changed anything that would interupt the connection to my device, or maybe the error is coming from somewhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem looks like is in the IDE. I tried clearing data in my emulator, reinstalling Flutter, but nothing seemed to work.

Switching from Visual Studio Code to Android Studio solved the problem.

When I run the command `flutter run` my app works fine in the emulator. This is a temporary solution for me as I will want to switch back to Visual Studio Code as it is my IDE of choice.

Comment: I think it's a bug with flutter. I'm having the same situation and this is half a year later. Where you ever able to solve it? I'm tired of running flutter run on terminal all the time.

Comment: @AxesGrinds I believe it's rather an issue with VS as I am having the same problem with a Xamarin.Forms app.